# Java compiler calls java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException without any reason

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, merge, queue

I am new to Java. I am trying to create a method for a custom PriorityQueue, that must uses an Array, which merges 2 PriorityQueues.

The problem is that while I have no errors in my code, the Java compiler in Eclipse calls java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException whenever I call that method in main.

About Merge method:
It's basically a method that takes the elements of 2 arrays and merges them into one array. Then it erases all the elements of the second array using the extractMax method:

So far my code is this:

```
//Custom Priority Queue
class PriorityQueue {
    private int capacity;
    private int queue[];
    private int i;

    public PriorityQueue() {
        capacity = 100;
        queue = new int[100];
        i = 0;
    }

    public PriorityQueue(int size) {
        capacity = size;
        queue = new int[size];
        i = 0;
    }

    protected void quickSort(int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        int pivot = queue[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (queue[i] > pivot)
                i++;
            while (queue[j] < pivot)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = queue[i];
                queue[i] = queue[j];
                queue[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (left < j)
            quickSort(left, j);
        if (i < right)
            quickSort(i, right);
    }

    public boolean insert(int number) {
        if(i < capacity) {
            queue[i] = number;
            quickSort(0, i++);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int extractMax() {
        if(i == 0)
            return -1;
        else {
            int tempQueue[] = new int[i-1];
            int temp = queue[0];

            for(int j=0; j<i-1; j++)
                tempQueue[j] = queue[j+1];
            queue = tempQueue;
            i--;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    public boolean merge(PriorityQueue myPriorityQueue) {
        if(i + myPriorityQueue.i < capacity) {
            for(int j=0; j<myPriorityQueue.i; j++)
                queue[i++] = myPriorityQueue.extractMax();
            quickSort(0, i-1);
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }

//Test Class
class PriorityQueueTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PriorityQueue PQ1 = new PriorityQueue();
        PriorityQueue PQ2 = new PriorityQueue();

        PQ1.insert(1);
        PQ1.insert(3);
        PQ1.insert(5);
        PQ2.insert(2);
        PQ2.insert(4);
        PQ2.insert(6);

        PQ1.merge(PQ2);     
    }
}
```

So whenever i Run this in eclipse i get:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at PriorityQueue.merge(PriorityQueue.java:89)
at PriorityQueueTest.main(PriorityQueueTest.java:22)
```

I tried to figure out why it does that, but it makes no sense. 
In this example, the length of the 2 PriorityQueues doesn't exceed the capacity of PriorityQueue1. There must be something wrong when I try to access PriorityQueues elements.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which line is line 89 ?

Comment: sry, it's line 88 actually and line 88 is: 

Queue[i++] = myPriorityQueue.extractMax();

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code line-by-line?

Comment: Just to clarify - the compiler doesn't call an exception, this happens runtime and the correct term is "throwing" an exception. The compiler does other things for you, e.g. checking that the index you're trying to access is an integer, but it doesn't know if this index exists. Only when the program is running can this be verified. At this point the compiler has done its job and is out of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(int j=0; j<myPriorityQueue.i; j++)
            Queue[i++] = myPriorityQueue.extractMax();
        QuickSort(0, i-1);
        return true;
```

More specifically, since you are incrementing `i` with `Queue[i++]` - and that's your class variable `i`, not a local one - `j` will always be less than `myPriorityQueue.i`. Therefore, this loop will always run until `j` exceeds `capacity` and throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception when you try to access a `Queue[]` element larger than its length. In a loop like this you would usually use `j` to access the elements in the array inside the loop:

```
for(int j=0; j<myPriorityQueue.i; j++)
            Queue[j] = myPriorityQueue.extractMax();
        QuickSort(0, i-1);
```

This way will only access elements in `Queue[]` up to `i`, and `j` automatically increments at the end of each iteration of the loop.

Things are made more confusing by your choice to use `i` as one of your class variables to track how many things are in the queue, instead of something more descriptive like `queued` or `stored`, when single letters such as `i` and `j` are often used in loops; you actually did use `i` in your QuickSort loop, when your class also already has a variable `i`. Using un-descriptive names for variables outside of loop counters is bad practice and makes code more difficult to understand.

Comment: So when I change the variable " i ", I also change the variable" myPriorityQueue.i "... You are right, thanks a lot man!!!!